# ASP.Net MVC display result from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Currently, we are displaying the outcome of stored procedure in View by using loops to create a HTML table. 
When the data is less (around 100 records) it works well. 
But when it come to large data, the page gets stuck till the whole table is created which takes minutes at times. 
I could not implement it with Web Grid.

**Question**
1. What is the best way to handle large amount of data for display?
2. How to display data in WebGrid if the result is coming from stored procedure?
3. Which one is good HTML table or WebGrid?

Comment: Have you looked at paging the results, say returning 50 records at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You have two use Jqgrid or Jquery Datatable plugin for web grid